# Can't enable dplyr and tidyr: libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found

Tags: r, package, r-googlesheets

After trying to install `googlesheets` package I can't enable `tidyr` and `dplyr` packages, as I get the following error:

```
require(dplyr)
Loading required package: dplyr
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/<username>/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/dplyr/libs/dplyr.so':
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/ccamara/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/dplyr/libs/dplyr.so)
```

I am running R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) -- "Wooden Christmas-Tree" under Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit) and dplyr 0.4.3 and tidyr 0.3.1

Can anyone give me some advice on this? Thank you!

Comment: Do you have `libstdc++6` installed? `sudo apt-get install libstdc++6` [source](http://askubuntu.com/questions/575505/glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found-how-to-fix-this-error)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/575505/glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found-how-to-fix-this-error

Comment: Have you restarted R since you installed `googlesheets` ? If you haven't, try it.

Comment: After trying all your answers with no success (I already had `libstdc++6` and restarted R session) + installed all ppas provided in the links I  uninstalled dplyr and installed it again from scratch and it worked. I am assuming it would have been a corrupted installation.